# Picking values from a multi-dimensional array using PHP & Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, multidimensional-array

So I have a multi-dimensional array, an example below. I want to pick out specific values from this in my view (I am using Laravel).

The data has been passed to my view.  I want all the names of users which I have done using:

```
@foreach ($users as $key => $value)
    {{ $key }}
@endfoeach
```

That is fine, it returns testuser, testuser1, and testuser2.

But in addition, I want to return just the domain and email from the inner array.  I can get all items no issues by creating a new loop but can't figure out how to get just specific items.

I appreciate any help.

```
Array
(
[testuser] => Array
    (
        [bandwidth] => 36.4/128000
        [domain] => test.com
        [email] => test@user.com
        [inodes] => 1566
    )

[testuser1] => Array
    (
        [bandwidth] => 36.41/128000
        [domain] => test.com
        [email] => test@user.com
        [inodes] => 1566
    )

[testuser2] => Array
    (
        [bandwidth] => 36.42/128000
        [domain] => test.com
        [email] => test@user.com
        [inodes] => 1566
    )
```

)

Comment: Have you tried regular array access, e.g. `$value['domain']`?

Comment: Hi, yes tried that.  Does not appear to work, wondering if this is a Laravel issue as that would work no problem just as standard PHP.

Comment: Oh, hell, sorry.  using     '$value['domain']' does work, it just needs to be wrapped in laravel blade like '{{ $value['domain'] }}

Comment: Of course, that means output :)

Comment: Indeed :) new to Laravel.